# Why there are no 5-byte and 6-byte code points in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

Why there are no 5-byte or 6-byte code points? I know they were till 2003 when they were removed. But I cannot find *why* were they removed.

The Wikipedia page on [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) says

> In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by [RFC 3629](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629) to match the constraints of the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) character encoding: explicitly prohibiting code points corresponding to the high and low surrogate characters removed more than 3% of the three-byte sequences, and ending at U+10FFFF removed more than 48% of the four-byte sequences and all five- and six-byte sequences.

but I don't understand why it's important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because there are no Unicode characters which would require them. And these cannot be added either because they'd be impossible to encode with UTF-16 surrogates.

Comment: So if I got it right, they were just not needed for now and when the need arises to add more characters to unicode, utf-16 will be extended to support them (I dunno, 6-byte utf-16 code point?) and utf-8 will have 5th&6th bytes re-enabled?

Comment: @Paladin: No, the Unicode people came to the conclusion that the need will not arise.

Comment: Unicode has a LONG LONG way to go before it ever reaches UTF-16's limit of 1112064 codepoints it can encode. UTF-8 originally supported 5-byte and 6-byte encodings, but was later restricted to 4-bytes max to be 100% compatible with UTF-16. If Unicode *ever* goes larger than UTF-16 can handle, a new UTF will have to be created (if not just use UTF-32) so maybe the 4-byte limit of UTF-8 might be lifted at that time.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)): "Currently, about ten percent of the potential space is used. Furthermore, ranges of characters have been tentatively mapped out for every current and ancient writing system (script) the Unicode Consortium has been able to identify. Even if previously unknown scripts with tens of thousands of characters are discovered, the limit of 1,114,112 code points is unlikely to be reached in the near future. The Unicode Consortium has stated that the limit will never be changed."

Answer (score 2):

I’ve heard some reasons, but did’t find any of them convincing. Basically, the stupid reason is: UTF-16 was specified before UTF-8 and at that time, 20 bits of storage for characters (yielding 2²⁰+2¹⁶ caracters minus a little like non-characters and surrogates for management) were deemed enough.

UTF-8 and UTF-16 are already variable-length encodings that, as you said for UTF-8, could be extended without big hastle (use 5- and 6-byte words). Extending UTF-32 to include 21 to 31 bits is trivial (32 could be a problem due to signdness), but making it variable-length defeats the use-case of UTF-32 completely.

Extending UTF-16 is hard, but I’ll try. Look at what UTF-8 does in a 2-byte sequence: The initial `110yyyyy` acts like a high surrogate and `10zzzzzz` like a low surrogate. For UTF-16, flip it around and re-use high surrogates as “initial surrogates” and low surrogates as “continue surrogates”. So, basically, you can have multiple low surrogates.

There’s a problem, though: Unicode streams are supposed to resist misinterpretation when you’re “tuning in” or the sender is “tuning out”.

- In UTF-8, if you read a stream of bytes and it ends with `11100010 10000010`, you *know for sure* the stream is incomplete. `1110` tells you: This is a 3-byte word, but one is still missing. In the suggested “extended UTF-16”, there’s nothing like that.
- In UTF-16, if you read a stream of bytes and it ends with a high surrogate, you *know for sure* the stream is incomplete.

The “tuning out” can be solved by using U+10FFFE as an announcement for a single UTF-32 encoding. If the stream stops after U+10FFFE, you know you’re missing something, same goes for an incomplete UTF-32. And if it stops in the middle of the U+10FFFE, it’s lacking a low surrogate. But that does not work becasue “tuning in” to the UTF-32 encoding can mislead you.

What could be utilized are so-called non-characters (the most well-known would be the reverse of the byte order mark) at the end of plane 16: Encode U+10FFFE and U+10FFFF using existing surrogates to announce a 3- or 4-byte sequence, repectively. This is very wasteful: 32 bits are used for the announcement alone, 48 or 64 additional bits are used for the actual encoding. However, it is still better than, say using U+10FFFE and U+10FFFF *around* a single UTF-32 encoding.

Maybe there’s something flawed in this reasoning. This is an argument of the sort: This is hard and I’ll prove it by trying and showing where the traps are.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE :

to test whether a code point lies within the surrogate range or not, instead of doing 2 relational comparisons, one could also do

> ```
>  floor( N / 2048 ) == 27
> ```

(this is identical to `4^5 * 54-or-55`, terms re-arranged)

===========================================

right now the space is allocated for `4^8 + 4^10` code points (CP), i.e. `1,114,112`, but barely 1/4 to 1/3rd of that is assigned to anything.

so unless there's a sudden need to add in another 750k CPs in a very short duration, up to 4 bytes for UTF-8 should be more than enough for years to come.

** just personal preference for

- `4^8 + 4^10`

on top of clarity and simplicity, it also clearly delineates the CPs by `UTF-8 byte count` :

```
 4 ^  8 =    65,536 = all CPs for 1-, 2-, or 3-bytes UTF-8
 4 ^ 10 = 1,048,576 = all CPs for            4-bytes UTF-8
```

instead of something unseemly like

```
 2^16 *  17
```

or worse,

```
 32^4 + 16^4
```

*** unrelated sidenote : *the cleanest formula-triplet I managed to conjure up for the starting points of the `UTF-16 surrogates` are :: *

```
 4^5 * 54 = 55,296 = 0x D800 = High - surrogates
 4^5 * 55 = 56,320 = 0x DC00 = Low  - surrogates
 4^5 * 56 = 57,344 = 0x E000 = just beyond the upper-boundary of 0x DFFF
```